# as3 upload file with PHP 5.4

Tags: php, actionscript-3

Does anyone know the way uploading a file with progress in PHP rel. 5.4 or higher?

I had a script in PHP 5.3 that worked fine uploading files but now that I have updated to php 5.4, things changed a lot. Now, the script do not work properly due to this line of code:

```
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
       .... In here is the code when the file is uploaded ......
    }
```

The fact is that **empty** do not work the same way as in php 5.3. so i can not figure out how it works.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using...

```
if (isset($_FILES))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
  if ($_FILES['error'] > 0)
    echo "An error occured" ;
  else
    echo "File loaded" ;// And proceed with upload
}
```

If you are expecting an input with name "file"